# React how to connect or reference the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, devextreme

I have question about how I can reference the enter key to the specific button.
To explain how the code is set up, I will explain it below.

So I have a file name v1 (component parent) and inside i have called many other components like v2 and v3 and so one.

*Below form is located on v1 component*

```
`<form onsubmit={this.click}>`
`<v2/>` <-- This component contains a grid where user can search info with 
search button 
`<v3/>`
`<button>Submit</button`>
`</form>`
```

So what i want to do is when user press the enter key it will reference the search button instead
of the submit button. Everytime when i click on the enter key, it will reference the submit button.
I searched on google and tried to use the ref on the button but it did not work... Also i am using the
devextreme with react.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to handle the submit. Then, you use a prevent default for submit and then call for search.

```js
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  // add code for search
};
```

Pass this handleSubmit as arg to onsubmit

```js
`<form onsubmit={this.handleSubmit}>`
`<v2/>` <-- This component contains a grid where user can search info with 
search button 
`<v3/>`
`<button>Submit</button`>
`</form>`
```